# Quark gluon plasma at arbitrarily high temperature

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, phase-diagram, quark-gluon-plasma, heavy-ion

Does the quark-gluon plasma become weakly coupled at infinite temperature (due to asymptotic freedom), or does it maintain some non-perturbative behavior?

Answer (score 1):

QGP develops perturbative properties early, when so called invariant measure $(Eps-3P)/T^4$ decreased enough - maybe above $T=0.4\ GeV$. Nobody looked seriously beyond $T=1\ GeV$ since we do not expect to find anything but very slow logarithmic approach  to ideal gas properties, and experimental reach ends before that value of $T$.